# How to list and rank associated records through a converging association in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

please excuse the Rail noob question. I'm trying to display a list of associated records, but am having trouble working out to handle associations in opposite directions.

For example, I have

```
Country
  has_many :states
  has_many :users, :through => :events
  has_many :venues, :through => :events
  has_many :users
  has_many :venues
end

State
  belongs_to :country
  has_many :cities
end

City
  belongs_to :state
  has_many :events
end

Event
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :venue
end

Venue
  has_many :events
  belongs_to :country
end

User
  has_many :events
  belongs_to :country
end
```

In the country show view I'm trying to list all events, all venues, and all users.

Events is straight forward

```
@country = Country.find(params[:id])
@events = @country.states.cities.events.find(:all)
```

But I'm having trouble visualizing a best approach to list users and venues.

The requirements are:

- Each individual User/Venue should be listed once with no duplicates.
- Users/Venues should be ordered based on the number of events they
  have (for the current country, not in total).

This seems like it should be fairly straightforward, but after playing with various permutations of `events.includes(:user)`, `.select("DISTINCT(ID)")` and `.order(user.events.length)` I've been unable to generate the query I need.

I think I'm probably stuck in a mental rut with this. I'd really appreciate some thoughts and ideas form the community to confirm whether or not I'm on the right rack.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

After I bit more thinking, I think my issue arrises from there being two associations between Country and User, an association via Event, and a direct association as part of an address. I've updated the model descriptions above.

As a consequence of this, on my country show page, how to I ensure that I'm listing users that are associated to a country through an event, and not through an address?

I am also getting duplicated Users. I've tried using `.uniq?` but that returns an error in some cases `'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object that returns a valid partial path.` I've also tried using `:select => "DISTINCT(ID)"` which so far seems a better fit. But what is the difference between these two approaches in terms of the way they interact with the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `:through` option with `:has_many` to get quick access for your deeply associated records:

```
Country
  has_many :states
  has_many :cities, through: :states # <-
  has_many :events, through: :cities # <-
  has_many :users, through: :events # <-
end

State
  belongs_to :country
  has_many :cities
  has_many :events, through: :cities # <-
  has_many :users, through: :events # <-
end

City
  belongs_to :state
  has_many :events
  has_many :users, through: :events # <-
end
```

And you can type simply: `@country.users`.

**UPD:**

To fetch all users of country's events try:

```
User.where(id: @country.events.uniq.pluck(:user_id))
```

Comment: thanks @jdoe, I appreciate your suggestion. My example code above was not complete, and I am already using through. After a bit more thinking, I think I've traced my problems to two issues: (1) there are two associations between my country and user models; (2) I don't think I'm fully understanding how uniq! and select distinct are working. I've updated my question with more details. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Check my UPD in the answer. I guess that's what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks jdoe, this looks promising. I will let you know how I get on.

Comment: Hi jdoe, i'm getting `undefined method 'pluck'`. Using Rails 3.2 on Postgres, Ruby 1.9.2. Any idea what would cause this?

Comment: `pluck` was introduced exactly in Rails 3.2.0. But here's workaround: `.map(&:user_id)`

Comment: this is working great to list the correct Users, thanks! I'm still having trouble ordering by the correct event.size though. Currently it seems to be ordering by total event.size, not country specific event.size. I may move this is a separate question if I don't get anywhere. Thanks for getting me this far.